# How to enclose a string within single quotes in Ansible

Tags: string, ansible, data-manipulation, single-quotes

Below is the string

```
ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 my$pass myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445
```

Desired output with password enclosed in single quotes:

```
ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 'my$pass' myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445
```

Below is my ansible playbook:

```
   - debug:
       msg: "utils.dbping string is {{ item.split()[0] ~ ' ' ~ item.split()[1] ~ ' \'' ~  item.split()[2] ~ '\' ' ~ item.split()[3] | trim }}"
     loop: 
       - ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 my$pass myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445
```

However, i get syntax error while executing:

The offending line appears to be:

```
       - debug:
           msg: "utils.dbping string is {{ item.split()[0] ~ ' ' ~ item.split()[1] ~ ' \'' ~  item.split()[2] ~ '\' ' ~ item.split()[3] | trim }}"
                                                                                       ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no use case description and no explanation is given, it looks just like a syntax error. You may have a look into the following example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

   - name: Quote in input
     debug:
       msg: "utils.dbping string is {{ item.split()[0] ~ ' ' ~ item.split()[1] ~ ' ' ~  item.split()[2] ~ ' ' ~ item.split()[3] | trim }}"
     loop:
       - ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 'my$pass' myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445

   - name: Quote in output
     debug:
       msg: "utils.dbping string is {{ item.split()[0] ~ ' ' ~ item.split()[1] ~ ' ' ~  item.split()[2] | quote ~ ' ' ~ item.split()[3] | trim }}"
     loop:
       - ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 my$pass myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Quote in input] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 'my$pass' myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445) =>
  msg: utils.dbping string is ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 'my$pass' myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445

TASK [Quote in output] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 my$pass myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445) =>
  msg: utils.dbping string is ORACLE_THIN PTEST1 'my$pass' myhost-SCA.mybank.com:1521/OLTP445
```

In both cases the desired one.

**Further Documentation**

- [Manipulating strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings)

  > *To add quotes for shell usage*